# How to properly replace HTML code for mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

[Source Code](http://codepen.io/koenkivits/pen/Jlgvx)

[Original article](http://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/)

I'm trying to make a basic layout for responsive webdesign, but i'm trying to do it by myself from scratch with html, css, and for mobile phone users javascript.

I want to embed the code in a way, that works with my current layout. Delete the ! in the if(...) at the bottom at the script to see my actual menu. The ! is only there for debugging purposes.

My problem is, that when i try to replace my normal menu, which is at top, the new menu does not work as intended, although it is directly copied through javascript. I also couldn't find any hint when inspecting the page in Firefox. Now i added a second item, just to make sure, that the css works as intended. I will update the design and content, once i know, that this method is compatible with my web-layout.

Note: The Home link is supposed to remain a link, because it has no sub-items.

Note 2: Don't actually click the links, i just wrote "link" specifically for this question. Only click the Item 1 and Item 2 to get the mobile drop-down menu.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .onclick-menu {
      position: relative;
      outline: 0;
      display: block;
      background-color: #DDD;
      height: 22px;
      width: 200px;
      border-color: blue;
      border-style: ridge;
      border-width: 5px;
    }
    .onclick-menu:before {
      content: attr(title);
      color: blue;
    }
    .onclick-menu:focus {
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    .onclick-menu:focus .onclick-menu-content {
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .onclick-menu-content {
      pointer-events: auto;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      transition: visibility .5s;
      background-color: #ddd;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: 19px;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .onclick-menu.no-pointer-events {
      pointer-events: auto!important;
    }
    .onclick-menu.no-visibility .onclick-menu-content {
      visibility: visible!important;
      display: none;
    }
    .onclick-menu.no-visibility:focus .onclick-menu-content {
      display: block;
    }
    .onclick-menu.no-opacity .onclick-menu-content {
      opacity: 1!important;
    }
    .onclick-menu-content:before {
      border-bottom: 10px solid #364656;
      border-left: 10px solid transparent;
      border-right: 10px solid transparent;
      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;
    }
    .onclick-menu-content li {
      color: #f2f5e9;
      list-style-type: none;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .onclick-menu-content button {
      background: transparent;
      border: none;
      color: inherit;
      outline: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .onclick-menu-content button:hover {
      color: #ff8c31;
    }
    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 6rem;
      min-height: 95%;
    }
    nav ul {
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      float: left;
    }
    nav ul a {
      display: block;
      background-color: #DDD;
      height: 22px;
      width: 200px;
      border-color: blue;
      border-style: ridge;
      border-width: 5px;
    }
    nav ul li {
      position: relative;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul ul {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0;
    }
    nav ul ul ul {
      top: 0;
      left: 210px;
    }
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
      display: block;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    nav ul ul a {
      border-color: green;
    }
    nav ul ul ul a {
      border-color: orange;
    }
    nav ul ul ul ul a {
      border-color: purple;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
  <section>
    <nav style="display:inline-flex;">
      <ul id="nav menu">
        <li><a href="link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="link menu item"><a href="link">Item 1</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link">Item 1_1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section>
    <article>
      <ul id="phone menu">
        <li>
          <a href="link">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu" title="Item 1">
            <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
              <li><a href="link">Item 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="link">Item 1_1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div tabindex="0" class="onclick-menu" title="Item 2">
            <ul class="onclick-menu-content">
              <li><a href="link">Item 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="link">Item 2_1</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </section>
  <script>
    if (!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|BB|PlayBook|IEMobile|Windows Phone|Kindle|Silk|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("link menu item");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].innerHTML = x[i].innerHTML.replace(x[i].innerHTML.split('<ul>')[0], "<a style=\"color:black\">" + x[i].innerText + "</a>");
      }
      document.getElementById("nav menu").innerHTML = document.getElementById("phone menu").innerHTML;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```